# Google Maps React - Making my markers clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose, google-maps-react

So I kinda got lost and I tried several codes. I managed to implement the markers however I think i'm doing something incorrect to make them actually clickable and display an InfoWindow.

Comment: can you share codesandbox here? it would be easier to resolve the issue. I would recommend to use react-google-maps it's community is strong.

Comment: Let me make a working codesandbox for you

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `Marker` by default isn't clickable, besides passing the onClick handler, you need to pass the `clickable` prop.

You can check all the `Marker` props in the documentation: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#marker

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out! I still can't figure out how to do that. Everything else on the map is clickable but not my markers..

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `react-google-maps` and `google-maps-react`. Here is the working example for your case:
Please add you APIkey in url.

```
App.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const { compose, withProps, withStateHandlers } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { InfoBox } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/InfoBox");


const App = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    center: { lat: 25.03, lng: 121.6 },
  }),
  withStateHandlers(() => ({
    isOpen: false,
  }), {
      onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => () => ({
        isOpen: !isOpen,
      })
    }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={5}
    defaultCenter={props.center}
  >

    <Marker
      position={{ lat: 22.6273, lng: 120.3014 }}
      onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
    >
      {props.isOpen && <InfoBox
        onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}
        options={{ closeBoxURL: ``, enableEventPropagation: true }}
      >
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: `yellow`, opacity: 0.75, padding: `12px` }}>
          <div style={{ fontSize: `16px`, fontColor: `#08233B` }}>
            no search place
          </div>
        </div>
      </InfoBox>}
    </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
);
export default App;
```

react-google-maps is smart component based using recomose but you can make it class base component too.

This is working codesandbox (temporarily live) : https://codesandbox.io/s/2wwjmx673r
Don't forget to add your API key.
feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Oh wow you're amazing! No wonder I had trouble after mixing those two lol.
Now my Maps.js is completely useless if I implement your code.EDIT:I still have to make the marker change color when i click it, and implement an info window there with a link from FourSquare or something... Should I do it in your code or make another .js file for Foursquare?

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Wait I just noticed the code won't let me add more markers?

Comment: How do i add more? I get an error right away if I try adding any <marker> tags

Comment: Okay!! Thank you very much

Comment: Hey there. So everything worked out fine. I had to re-do my entire thing from scratch because It was difficult for me to understand the logic behind everything, but thank you so much!
Either way, I need your help again. This is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/0338vv69zv
And for some reason my markers dont change color when clicked. I'm also trying to figure out how to implement an InfoBox in there again lol. Do you know how to implement a FourSquare window inside of the info window when clicked?

Comment: Sure. Happy to help

Comment: Sorry my comment was sent before I could finish writing, i edited it

Comment: okay. But you must post another question on stackoverflow So coomunity will be aware of it If someone would face the issue in future. Then your posts will be helpful for particular issues. and You should accept this one as it served your purpose previously. I hope this would make sense.

Comment: oh yeah it makes sense. It just won't let me post since I'm new on stack overflow so I have to wait until tomorrow... Which is why I asked you because you know this area so well